# How to inject a list with different implementations of the same interface in a nested module scenario via Guice?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

There is an interface DCE, which is implemented by a class DCEImpl which has a dependency, say, string S, which it gets via its constructor.

The universe of S is limited, say S can only take values {'A','B','C'}.

There is an already existing Guice module that accepts the value of S in its constructor, and then binds the interface DCE to the correctly initialized version of DCEImpl.

```
public class DCEModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final String s;
    public DCEModule(String s){
       this.s = s;
    }
    protected void configure() {
      bind(DCE.class).toInstance(new DCEImpl(s));
    }
}
```

Now I have a class `C` which needs a `List<DCE>` with all the 3 implementations (actually a lot more than 3, using 3 for example purpose).

I want to inject this list via Guice in `C`. To do that, I created a new module `DCEPModule`, which will provide a `List<DCE>` in this way:

```
@Provides
List<DCE> getDCE() {
      for(String s: S){
            Module m = new DCEModule(s);
            install(m);
            Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(m);
            listDomains.add(injector.getInstance(DCE.class));
        }
}
```

My problem is that I don't want to call a new injector in this module, because `DCEPModule` will be installed by a different module.

```
public class NewModule extends AbstractModule {
   protected void configure() {
      install(DCEPModule);
    }
```

}

I want a way to get the `List<DCE>` without explicitly creating a new injector in `DCEPModule`.

Comment: Do you want to automatically scan for implementations or do you want to control which implementations will be in the list?

Comment: I want all the available implementations in the list, and I have a way to know them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a `Multibinder` ([javadoc](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/multibindings/Multibinder.html), [wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings)). 
Here’s an example:

```
public class SnacksModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure(){
         Multibinder<Snack> multibinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), Snack.class);
         multibinder.addBinding().toInstance(new Twix());
         multibinder.addBinding().toProvider(SnickersProvider.class);
         multibinder.addBinding().to(Skittles.class);
    }
}
```

Now, the multibinder will provide a `Set<Snack>`. If you absolutely need a `List` instead of a `Set`, then you can add a method to your module like this:

```
@Provides
public List<Snack> getSnackList(Set<Snack> snackSet) {
    return new ArrayList(snackSet);
}
```

You can add implementations to the same Multibinding in more than one module. When you call `Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder, type)` it doesn’t necessarily create a new Multibinding. If a Multibinding already exists for for that type, then you will get the existing Multibinding.